# saving file into small parts then combine them and write to sdcard

Tags: android, file, http, sd-card

Is there any way to splitting file into n numbers of parts?

I want to read from a HTTP connection and write bytes to a file in android.

But when the size of that file exceeds `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` it is closing the connection.

Is there any way to manage memory so that a big file can also be read and write to sdcard in android.

Comment: You would want to not read the entire file into memory first... just read small chunks then write them as you read.